# Settings for postgres: update existing db or create new

Tags: postgresql, pg-settings

I have a local postgres db, and some query is executed ok on it, but the query does not work on production db. So I get the production db settings to reproduce the error. The settings looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO pg_settings
("name",setting,unit,category,short_desc,extra_desc,context,vartype,"source",min_val,max_val,enumvals,boot_val,reset_val,sourcefile,sourceline,pending_restart)
VALUES
('debug_assertions', 'off', NULL, 'Preset Options', 'Shows whether the running server has assertion checks enabled.' ,NULL, 'internal', 'bool', 'default', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'off' ,'off' ,NULL, NULL, false), 
...
etc
```

When I'm trying to execute the script, I'm getting

```
SQL Error [55000]: ERROR: cannot insert into view "pg_settings"
Detail: Views that do not select from a single table or view are not automatically updatable.
Hint: To enable inserting into the view, provide an INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger or an unconditional ON INSERT DO INSTEAD rule.
```

What I need is either apply this settings to existing local db or create a new one using this settings. How can I do it? Sorry for lame question :(

Comment: `... but the query does not work on production db.` Please define *doesn't work*. Why do you think that turnig on assertions would solve your problem? And: I really don't think that assertions are turned on on production. [this appears to be an XY-problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation for `pg_settings`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/view-pg-settings.html) explains that

> The view pg_settings provides access to run-time parameters of the
>   server. It is essentially an alternative interface to the SHOW and SET
>   commands. It also provides access to some facts about each parameter
>   that are not directly available from SHOW, such as minimum and maximum
>   values.

and

> The pg_settings view cannot be inserted into or deleted from, but it
>   can be updated

I would use `SHOW ALL` on both servers and compare the results to see what is different if these settings are indeed relevant to your problem.

Alternatively, you can use this query on both servers:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_settings ORDER BY category, context, "name"
```

and then export as text and compare the results.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't configurable outside of building the binaries.  This is just an indicator as to whether your build of PostgreSQL was configured with debug assertions enabled or not.  This cannot be changed.  You would either need to rebuild PostgreSQL from source with this set to true, or request a build from your vendor with it enabled.